# Any shortcut to uninstall the current App in Xcode Simulator quickly?

Tags: xcode

In Android Studio, I could press

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the current App of the project (opened in Android Studio) will be uninstalled from the Emulator.

Is there an equivalent shortcut in Xcode for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Not a shortcut, but xcode's simulator control command line `xcrun simctl` has options to uninstall an app if you know it's bundle id.

Some references for sim ctl:

https://nshipster.com/simctl/

https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc

You can create a keyboard shortcut or a service using this if you really need it.